# Get absolute directory path from %absolute_file_path% in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Given an absolute path stored in variable:

```
SET absolute_file_path=C:\path\containing\some.json
```

using command prompt, how to extract absolute directory path `C:\path\containing\` or `C:\path\containing` out of `%absolute_file_path%`?

Comment: You have used the batch-file tag, and answers have been provided using batch files. Your question however is specific, to using the command prompt. You need to clarify your requirements by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48130180/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` has some modifiers to get parts of a path\filename:

```
SET absolute_file_path=C:\path\containing\some.json
for %%A in (%absolute_file_path%) do (
  echo file name: %%~nA
  echo file extension: %%~xA
  echo full file name: %%~nxA
  echo drive: %%~dA
  echo path: %%~pA
  echo drive/path: %%~dpA
  echo full qualified filename: %%~fA
)
```

a `call`ed subroutine has the same modifiers. See `for /?` and `call /?`

Comment: Thanks, I wrapped variable in quotes as some paths had spaces in the payload: `for %A in ("%absolute_file_path%") do echo %~dpA`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
SET absolute_file_path=C:\path\containing\some.json

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set I=0
set L=-1
:l
if "!absolute_file_path:~%I%,1!"=="" goto ld
if "!absolute_file_path:~%I%,1!"=="\" set L=%I%
set /a I+=1
goto l
:ld
echo %L%

CALL SET ab_path=%%absolute_file_path:~0,%L%%%

echo %ab_path%
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually answers your question:

```dos
C:\Users\Annie>Set "absolute_file_path=C:\path\containing\some.json"
C:\Users\Annie>For %A In ("%absolute_file_path%") Do @Echo %~dpA
```